# Botão de buscar/confirmar e limpar campo

Tags: php, javascript, html

Preciso que quando o usuário clicar sobre o botão **"BUSCAR/CONFIRMAR"** abra uma nova janela no navegador pedindo para **SELECIONAR** uma das categorias que vem diretamente do banco de dados, e ao selecionar a mesma janela fecha e o valor escolhido vai pro campo e só seria possível mudar a categoria clicando no botão **"LIMPAR CAMPO"** e fazendo todo processo novamente.

É tudo através de javascript, mas infelizmente não tenho esse conhecimento.

**Input e os botões:** (O input por padrão é desativado):

```
  <div class="input_field"><label for="num"><b>Categoria</b>            :</label>
        <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="categoria" size="65"><br>
        <div style="margin-left:105px;"><a class="busca"><font color='#FFFFFF'>Buscar/Confirmar</font></a>
       <a class="voltar"> <font color='#FFFFFF'>Limpar o Campo</font></a></div><br>
        </div>
```

**Categorias.php** (Nova janela)

```
        <table width="100%">
           <thead>
            <tr>
 <th><center><font class="cinza_peq">Selecione</font></center></th>
    <th><center><font class="cinza_peq">ID</font></center></th>
    <th><center><font class="cinza_peq">Nome da Categoria</font></center></th>

</tr>
</thead>
<?php
$sql_pai = "SELECT * FROM cms_news_cat ORDER BY ID";
$res_pai = mysql_query($sql_pai) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res_pai)){ ?>

 <td><center><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $row['nome']; ?>" /></center></td>
<td><center><?php echo $row['id']; ?></center></td>
<td><center><?php echo $row['title']; ?> <u></u> </center></td>

</tr>
    <?php } ?>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione um `onclick` em cada `<a>` para chamar duas funções: uma para abrir a nova janela e outra para limpar o campo:

```
<a class="busca" onclick="janela()"><font color='#FFFFFF'>Buscar/Confirmar</font></a>
<a class="voltar" onclick="limpar()"> <font color='#FFFFFF'>Limpar o Campo</font></a>
```

E adicione o script com as funções:

```
<script>
function janela(){
   if(document.body.querySelector("input[name='categoria']").value == '') window.open("categorias.php", "categorias", "...");
}

function limpar(){
   document.body.querySelector("input[name='categoria']").value = '';
}
</script>
```

> Onde tem `"..."` no `window.open` você pode definir as propriedades da
>   janela ([veja aqui as opções](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)).

No arquivo `categorias.php` você deve dar um mesmo `name` para cada `input radio`, por exemplo:

```
<input type="radio" name="categoria" value="<?php echo $row['nome']; ?>" />
```

E nesse mesmo arquivo `categorias.php`, insira o script:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var radios = document.body.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']");

   for(var x=0; x<radios.length; x++){

      radios[x].addEventListener("click", function(){

         window.opener.document.body.querySelector("input[name='categoria']").value = this.value;
         self.close();

      });

   }
});
</script>
```

Ao selecionar um `radio`, o seu `value` será lançado no `input` da página principal e a janela se fechará.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, funcionou perfeitamente!